# checking and reading cookies with nginx

Tags: nginx, http-cookie

I can't find many resources on how to manage cookies with Nginx…

I've seen that two variables are relatives to cookies, that is $http_cookies and $cookie_COOKIENAME.

Anyway, I absolutely don't know how to read a cookie with Nginx.

For exemple, i'd like to return a 403 if a cookie with a special value exists, i tried this but that doesn't seem to work :

```
if ($cookie_mycookiename = "509fd1e420bba") { return 403; }
```

also tried with $http_cookie

```
if ($http_cookie = "509fd1e420bba") { return 403; }
```

I really don't understand how Nginx handles cookies…

EDIT
here is my full Nginx config

```
server {

listen 80;

root /home/minou/vids/;
index index.html index.htm;

#server_name localhost;


location / {

# First attempt to serve request as a file, then
# as directory, then fall back to index.html

try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

if ($cookie_fileURI = "6509fd1e420bba") { return 403; }
}

# anti hotlinking
location ~* \.(jpg)$ {
valid_referers none blocked mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
if ($invalid_referer) { return 403; }

}

}
```

Comment: Your 'if' statement seems correct. Maybe it is something else that is not working. Can you post your entire configuration?

Comment: my config file is quite simple, anyway, i've edited my post to add it. is there a way to check the value of either $http_cookie or $cookie_COOKIE as that might help ?

Answer (score 4):

Please be aware that using `if` within a `location` might not work as expected, specially when used together with `try_files`. See: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Please try this:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    root /home/minou/vids/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    #server_name localhost;

    if ($cookie_fileURI = "6509fd1e420bba") { return 403; }

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # anti hotlinking
    location ~* \.(jpg)$ {
        valid_referers none blocked mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
        if ($invalid_referer) { return 403; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
if ($http_cookie ~* "cookiename=cookievalue") {return 403}
```